# remove all #EXTM3U from string

Tags: php, preg-match, str-replace, preg-match-all

I am trying to remove all the `#EXTM3U` from my big string. My current code doesn't remove anything and gives no result! What i am doing wrong here?

```
$test_value = preg_match_all("#EXTM3U", "", $input_value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because you are missing [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and aren't using it in a replace context.

```
$test_value = preg_replace("/#EXTM3U/", "", $input_value);
```

should work.

Furthermore though you aren't using a regex here so a simpler solution would be using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$test_value = str_replace("#EXTM3U", "", $input_value);
```

Also note `$input_value` will still have the string you want removed; `$test_value` will have the string without the `#EXTM3U`.

You also might prefer, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php. If case is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

When you use preg_match you're looking to match the value in the whole thing.

If you do the following you're looking to replace content:

```
$test_value = str_replace("#EXTM3U", "", $input_value)
```

Comment: I copied it from some of my other code, thanks for pointing out the modification I forgot.